# Web Audio connect meter

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to connect an audio meter like suggested in this tutorial
http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound

My app uses wavesurfer ( http://www.wavesurfer.fm/ ) to load and visualise audio files, but I haven't figured out how to connect a meter to a wavesurfer object.

**EDIT**

I realised that each wavesurfer track has already an analyser, so I tried hoonking up to it like follows:

```
analyser = Daw.tracks[0].backend.analyser;

Daw.tracks[0].backend.scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {

// get the average for the first channel
var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
var average = getAverageVolume(array);

 // clear the current state
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 60, 130);

 // set the fill style
 ctx.fillStyle=gradient;

 // create the meters
 ctx.fillRect(0,130-average,25,130);}
```

and it seems to be working.